# touchmove and mousemove preventing vertical scroll on iPad

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, uiscrollview, swipe, touchmove

I’ve been working on an iOS iPad app for a school project using `jQuery.touchSwipe.min.js` code that will allow for the user to swipe horizontally between pages.

However, I discovered that it's preventing scrolling up and down for content in which the height is greater than the iPad screen. If I remove this bit of code, "touchmove":"mousemove", from jQuery.touchSwipe.min.js, I can get the scrolling effect again vertically, but then the horizontal swipe between pages stops!

How I can keep the horizontal swipe between pages while scrolling vertically on a page?

Comment: Why aren't you using native jQuery Mobile swipe events? As you are using swipe to navigate between pages?

Answer (score 0):

check the below link, it might be helpful.

http://gregsramblings.com/2012/05/23/preventing-vertical-scrolling-bounce-using-javascript-on-ios-devices/